# Extending `Function` in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I want to extend `Function.prototype`, but on a new prototype which I'll call `Func`. I want to do this to modify the `toString` method. I've been trying a load of things to achieve this, but I can't seem to come up with anything. Can this be done, and if so, what is the best way to it?

Ideally I'd want to do `f = new Func(function () {})` and then later call `f.toString` to use my modified `toString` method.

Comment: This is normal prototype inheritance, where your `Func` inherits from `Function`, with `Func.prototype.toString` shadowing Function.toString - there are lots of tutorials online to teach you how to write that up, simply search for "javascript inheritance"

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'd like to see a JSFiddle. I wasn't joking when I said I tried a load of stuff.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: Oh, there's not much "normal" about `new Function`....

Comment: @RyanSmith perhaps you can expand on your need, then; The syntax `f = new Func(function () {})` suggests a plain object that wraps a function, not an extension of (or rewrite for the prototype of) the Function object. T.J.Crowder's right on the "why?" front, though. If you're wrapping, why not just have a function `toString(fn) { return ... }` that turns any Function input into the string you want?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've already considered that, but then I'd need to do something like `wrapperObj.func()` to call it, which is pretty barmy (not that this whole idea isn't a bit barmy anyway).

Comment: Okay, so let's back up - what are you trying to do? Not how are you trying to do it, but what are you trying to do that requires a function's toString() to not return its string representation but something else? Because a million to one, this solution isn't a good one.

Comment: I'd just like to change the toString implementation for a Function, but obviously I don't want to screw with the Function prototype. I want the methods to be put on the prototype for efficiency and chaining.

Comment: @RyanSmith: Again, there's nothing inefficient about setting a single property on the functions passed through `Func`.

Comment: I'm chaining though, I don't want to keep doing that every time I chain. I.e. `Func(function () {})(a)(b)(b)`. Chaining on a, b, c, etc would not be good if I'm assigning properties each time right?

Comment: I should say that it's not just the `toString` method that I'd like to add.

Comment: you can't replace a prototype on some instances, it has to be all or nothing. you can tack an own property on some of them, or use Object.create to inherit from Function.prototype, and then define your own toString(), but i doubt it would be any quicker. modifying a native prototype leads to slower, less efficient
 code, not the other way around.

Comment: @dandavis you can't use `Object.create`. I'm not modifying a native prototype, I'm extending it, and in my case the alternative is to add methods sequentially to a function every time I call a function, hence there is a massive performance hit.

Comment: well, there are middle paths between pollution and over-iteration. For example, anything a Function.prototype.method can do, so can a regular function, or another method, using call/apply/bind, ex: "".bold.call(alert); If you do go the proto-modifying route, you can put all your methods behind a single method to avoid polluting as much, a call would look like alert.mod().toString2(). (you need to invoke the "namespace" to capture your orig function as _this_). Lastly, maybe you could make the function an object instead, and use func.fn() instead of func(), which provides a ton of freedom...

Comment: the problem is that only native functions, inheriting from Function.prototype, can execute. if you need methods on executable, on-demand addition or prototype modification are your only options. you can't return a function from a custom constructor, you need to "return this" in constructors in order to inherit any methods.

Comment: I think I'll probably do something like `func.fn()`. Thanks @dandavis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this, I would say that the only answer is not to do this. I was able to find other ways of achieving what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I have a **strong** sense of ***why?!*** for this question, but you can do it like this:

```
function Func(f) {
    f.toString = Func$toString;
    return f;
}
```

...where `Func$toString` is your `toString` implementation.

Example:

```js
function Func$toString() {
  return "Special! " + Function.prototype.toString.call(this);
}
function Func(f) {
  f.toString = Func$toString;
  return f;
}

var f = new Func(function () {});
display(f); // "Special! function () {}"

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = String(msg);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

---

Or, of course, if you're feeling really daring, just replace `Function.prototype.toString`:

```js
var oldToString = Function.prototype.toString;
Function.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "Special! " + oldToString.call(this);
};

var f = function () {};
display(f); // "Special! function () {}"

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = String(msg);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Comment: That's not really what I'm looking for. I need to use the prototype for efficiency.

Comment: @RyanSmith: You can't (in ES5), by the time the argument `function () {}` is evaluated, its prototype is already assigned. But there's nothing inefficient about the above. We're not duplicating the `Func$toString` function or anything like that, just giving the object its own property. Object get ***lots*** of properties.

Comment: That's what I thought, never mind. I thought it was worth a try on here.

Comment: @RyanSmith: In ES6, you'll have [`setPrototypeOf`](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-reflect.setprototypeof), but I doubt it'll be more efficient in any real-world terms.

Comment: Oh right nice! That sounds like just the ticket, thanks for your help! I guess it won't be so bad, but I want to check there is no way to improve it first.